# What is default Server URL for creating openshift project using eclipse plugin?

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, openshift-client-tools, jboss-tools, openshift-cartridge

I am trying to create openshift application using jboss plugin in eclipse.
While creating project I given following server URL: https://openshift.redhat.com
and choose authentication protocol as basic and provided correct user id and password. But after pressing Next button I am getting following error: 
**"Unable to read endpoint https://openshift.redhat.com/api"**

I also tried https://console.preview.openshift.com/console/ server URL, Still I am getting same error.

Please let me know what is the correct server URL for creating openshift application?

Comment: Which version of OpenShift are you trying to use. The first URL is for OpenShift 3. You have tagged the question with ``openshift-cartridge`` though, which pertains to OpenShift 2. And what instructions are you trying to follow for this. Link?

Comment: I used following link:  https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-eclipse-jboss-tools-openshift-online-3/ and Server type I am using is Openshift 3

Comment: What the URL will be will depend on what OpenShift cluster you are using. If you were using OpenShift Online starter tier and were on the us-east-1 cluster, the URL would possibly be ``https://console.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com``. Which OpenShift cluster are you using? What is the URL of the web console when you are logged in? Drop the path off the end and try it.

Comment: As I new to openshift, I don't know where do I get "which cluster I am using". Will you please tell me where do I find "which cluster I am using"? After landing I am at link https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/ is this what you want?

Comment: While creating application I chosen aws-us-east-1 as region and tried with the https://console.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com but same result "Unable to read endpoint"

Comment: Were you able to get the access token okay for your login session?

Comment: No. When I click on Retrieve new token I am getting following error "This page can’t be displayed. Make sure the web address https://api.aws-us-east-1.openshift.com is correct."

Comment: Are you entering ``api.aws-us-east-1.openshift.com`` in somewhere or is that what the eclipse plugin for OpenShift is generating? It should be using ``api.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com``.

Comment: http://api.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com is worked but I am getting following error "You do not have access to OpenShift Online". But I can create applications with online interface.

Comment: Are you using a current token. Tokens are expired every 24 hours.

Comment: That is not allowing me to generate Token. Before that I am getting that error."You do not have access to OpenShift Online"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149777/discussion-between-sandip-patil-and-graham-dumpleton).

Comment: You have to log into the web console to get to the token. Once you are logged in, go to the Command Line Tools menu from the question mark top right. This gives you the command to run to log in from the command line. That includes a token, or once you have run that, use ``oc whoami -t`` to get the token.